ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied : Check the permissions
I want to install Spacy in the virtual environment. I created the virtual environment with python 3.9. Activated the environment. As per theSpacy tutorial when I tried to install Spacy in the virtual environment I received error as follows
Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\env39\lib\site-packages (21.2.4)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\env39\lib\site-packages (58.1.0)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-70.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (863 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 863 kB 2.2 MB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 65 kB 1.9 MB/s
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 58.1.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-58.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-58.1.0
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.2.4
    Uninstalling pip-21.2.4:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\env39\\scripts\\pip.exe'
Check the permissions.

I searched on Google and found that I need to use --user with the command to run it properly. Therefore, I tried that and got the error as follows

Then I tried to install pip

Then I again tried the same command to install Spacy. Now the situation is as follows

How can I solve it?

For :

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied


Check the permissions.

You need to run Command Prompt as Administrator



Other workarounds:

Close all the instances of Python currently running on your machine.

Go to Scripts Folder. Right click --> Properties --> Allow Full Control and other read write operations.




Running command prompt as administrator did not change anything

I have added other options. I would also recommend you to restart your machine and install spacy with admin rights from the scratch.
